# Where is trac.ini?

Tags: web-hosting, dreamhost

I have set up trac with Dreamhost One-Click Install. The doc says config is in trac.ini but I can't see any under trac dir. Where would it be?

I have no conf dir, ONLY admin, db, htdocs, prefs, etc...

Answer (score 3):

It's usually inside the `conf` folder, underneath your trac project's install directory. Something like:

```
trac_sites/conf/trac.ini
```

Comment: I have no conf dir ONLY admin, db, hrdocs, prefs, etc...